# Background image not working in my safari

Tags: css, safari

My css code working fine in chrome but in safari it is not working at all

```
.bg-gradient-dark {
    background-image: linear-gradient(
310deg
, #141727 0%, #3A416F 100%);
   
}
```

Comment: what is your Safari version? According to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image), you might have to add `-webkit` vendor prefix.

Comment: @Raptor version 14.1.2 (14611.3.10.1.7)

Comment: Is there any other relevant CSS? I can’t get the code you have given to go wrong. Could you put a snippet we can run into your question and test it to make sure it shows the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

```
.bg-gradient-dark {
    background-image: linear-gradient(310deg, #141727 0%, #3A416F 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(310deg, #141727 0%, #3A416F 100%);
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(310deg, #141727 0%, #3A416F 100%);
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(310deg, #141727 0%, #3A416F 100%);
    background-image:         linear-gradient(to 310deg, #141727 0%, #3A416F 100%);
}
```

you need to add prefix, so it can work in another browser
The major browsers use the following prefixes:

```
-webkit- (Chrome, Safari, newer versions of Opera, almost all iOS browsers including Firefox for iOS; basically, any WebKit based
browser)
-moz- (Firefox)
-o- (old pre-WebKit versions of Opera)
-ms- (Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge)
```

here is the Docs from MDN about [prefix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix)